# How to execute an update after each item writing in Spring batch?

Tags: spring-batch

I am doing a database read and database write as spring task. It's running fine. The after job method also is getting executed fine. But my requirement is after each insert of an entry I need to update a flag in the source database. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [CompositeItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemWriter.html) - that has 2 delegate writers

1. Delegate writer 1 - performs the insert into the target database
2. Delegate writer 2 - update the status in the source database

If you really need to commit after each insert - you will need to set the commit-interval for the step to 1. Do remember that setting the commit interval 1 means very low performance - so unless there is a compelling reason do not set the commit interval to 1

Answer (score 0):

if the inserted data contains some data to identify the insert happened (insert date, status flag, etc.) you could run a simple [Taskletstep](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#taskletStep) which executes an update statement like

```
update .... 
set flag = flag.value 
where insert.date = ....
```